# Disabling console logging with http.get

Tags: node.js, testing, bdd

I have this code:

```
var should = require('should'),
  http = require('http'),
  apis = {
    baseUrl: 'http://11.0.0.20:4000',
    listLiveMatches: '/api/blah/'
  };
describe('GET ' + apis.baseUrl + apis.listLiveMatches, function () {
  'use strict';
  var liveListUrl = apis.baseUrl + apis.listLiveMatches;
  it('is alive & returning 200', function (done) {
    http.get(liveListUrl, function (res) {
      res.should.be.ok;
      res.should.have.property('statusCode');
      res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
      done();
    });
  });
  it('is emitting json response', function (done) {
    http.get(liveListUrl, function (res) {
      res.should.be.ok;
      res.should.have.property('headers');
      res.headers['content-type'].should.startWith('application/json');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

My gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('test-server', function () {

  return gulp.src('test/rest-api.js')
    .pipe(mocha({
      reporter: 'spec'
    }))
    .on('error', function(){
      console.log('error');
    });
});
```

My only issue is that with every http.get, the console gets the body of the response logged which I want to prevent, google searches for disabling logging on http.get have yielded nothing.

Comment: What happens when you run the test file straight from mocha and not through gulp?

Comment: @R.A.Lucas works fine when I invoke it directly through mocha with just the pass or fail results being shown.